# How does Openflow decide which path to use?

Tags: router, controller

In current networks, OSPF ,RIP,etc  determine the path taken by a packet. In SDN, the OpenFlow protocol sets the flow tables of the forwarding units. Can someone be very clear that how does OpenFlow decide which path to set for a flow?

Comment: Or tell me the place where I can get this answer.

Comment: You will likely get a better answer at http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/